# Form data (array type) -> Database (serialize text) in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony

My database has a column named 'value' which used to store data from submit form. It's a 'text' type. How can I do to store an array from Form, I mean I want to serialize array data before save it to database?

For example I have

```
builder->add('countries', 'country', array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false
            )
        )
```

and I want to store this countries data to 'value' column.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `array` column type in doctrine. List of possible mapping types you can find in [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types).

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 */
private $countries = array();
```